# PayUMoney payment method for sandbox is not showing in frontend for Magento 1.9

Tags: payment-gateway, magento-1.9, payumoney

I downloaded PayuMoney payment extension for Magento 1.9 from their website and copied the respective directories/code in the app folder.

In the Admin, it is showing the configuration settings for this extension where I entered following details as instructed in the integration guide document:

```
Enabled: ​ ‘Yes’                         
Environment: sandbox               
PayUmoney Key: Test key as    provided in the guide (for testing purpose)  
PayUmoney Salt:​ Test    salt as provided in the guide (for testing purpose)  
Citrus Payment/Vanity Url: Blank  
Citrus Access Key:​ Blank  
Citrus Secret Key: Blank  
Route (%): Blank
```

[Refer the screenshot: PayuMoney extension setting in Magento Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHsFi.png)
I want to test the functionality hence want to use sandbox environment with test credentials provided in the guide. But with above configuration setting, PayuMoney is not coming up for the customer in the checkout page as a payment option.

I checked related threads but it has not helped much. Appreciate if anyone has any idea to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

PayUMoney does not have payment options for sandbox so you can only use the card option using the test card credentials given on the website. If you want to check transactions with other options you need to check those in Live Mode only. Note that in live mode you'll be having all the payment options.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There will be two options:

```
Route to PayUMoney = 100
Route to Citrus  = 0
```

Fill these values it will work.

Comment: Hey, this solution is work for after setting this value payUmoney option start showing. Thank you